# Reshaping Embedding layer output for Conv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Embedding layer has output shape of

```
embedding_4 (Embedding)         (None, 10, 50)
```

Where 10 is the number of words and 50 is the dimension of the vector. How to reshape the tensor to give it input to a

```
Conv2D(50,(2,50),padding='same',activation='relu')
```

layer. Using Keras for writing the code.

Comment: you need to use Conv1D for 3d sequences

Comment: Can't I use Conv2D?

Comment: simply no, why Conv2D ?

Answer (score 0):

So as the comment suggests that it will be better if you use `Conv1D` as the input needed by `Conv1D` is of rank [`3`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D). Also, for `Conv2d` you will need to have the input with rank [`4`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D).

You can do the following to actually reshape your input.

```
example = np.zeros((32,10,50))

reshape = np.expand_dims(example , axis=1)
```

Output will be:

```
(32, 1, 10, 50)
```

You can also use the reshape layer API from Keras as shown below.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1, 10, 50), input_shape=(10, 50)))

model.output_shape
```

Output shape will be as follows:

```
(None, 1, 10, 50)
```

Just as a note `None` will be your `batch_size` and `1` be your channel.

But also like the comment suggests that you should ask yourself what benefit `Conv2D` will bring that `Conv1D` doesnot.